# Docker friendlyhello failing to build

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I've created the Docker files described in the [Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app) documentation.  The build step is failing as below:

```
PS > docker build -t friendly-hello .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  60.93kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:2.7-slim
2.7-slim: Pulling from library/python
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

I suspect it's because I'm working with Windows containers and the documentation hasn't been updated to include this.

How do I go about correcting this error?

Comment: Are you using docker on Windows OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is probably obvious to anyone why used Docker regularly, however, for any newbies like me here's the cause of the error and the solution.

I'm using Windows containers, rather than Linux ones which the documentation was for.

```docker
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim
```

This is telling Docker that there's a dependency on an image in the Docker hub called `python` and tagged `2.7-slim`.  You can find the by browsing to https://hub.docker.com and searching for `python`.  Clicking on the python will take you to the [python repository page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).

The information on the tag doesn't make it obvious which tags support which architectures, however some have `windowsservercore` in their tag name which suggests quite strongly that these support windows.

Changing the line requesting `python:2-7-slim` to `python:2.7.15-windowsservercore` solves the problem i.e.:

```docker
FROM python:2.7.15-windowsservercore
```